# How to call constructor in the method using ionic2?

Tags: ionic2

I am new to ionic 2, we want to call a constructor within the method how can I call

```
export class OtpPage {
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
                public formBuilder:FormBuilder, public logger: Logger,
                public rest: Rest) {

         this.customer_id=this.navParams.get('customer_id');
         this.mobile=this.navParams.get('mobile');
         this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
            'otpNumber': ['', Validators.required]
         });

        submit() {
            if(result.status=='1'){ 
                this.firstDiv=false;
                this.secondDiv = true;
                this.logger.debug("checking access tocken "+   
                this.access_token);
                alert("otp success");
        }
  }
```

within these if loop how can I call constructor when the `this.secondDiv`=true

Comment: Why put all this logic in the constructor? Create a seperate function which you call once in your constructor. Then you can just recursively call that function

Comment: bro....I wanted to call the function inside the constructor it means the formBuilder is inside the constructor...

Comment: But you declared the `formBuilder` as `public` so you can just call `this.formBuilder` from a different function